# Manually tweak env/stack/semantic value to achieve an error recovery

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir, error-recovery

I'm trying to implement error recovery in [this version of the project](https://github.com/chengtie/menhir-error-recovery/commit/adfee435f4ef4552f4f6cc3e7e76aa3f47db355b) (`make` followed by `./parse e1.input` to test).

Given `(1` in `e1.input`, I would like the parser to act as if it parsed `)` and build an AST `Paren (Int 1)`. Thus, I tried

```
let (startp, endp) = positions in
let _ = feed (T T_RPAREN) startp () endp env in
```

However, it returned an error `Invalid_argument("feed: outgoing transition does not exist")`

```
hahahaha depth of env 2
hahahaha current_state_number 2
hahahaha startp 1:1
hahahaha endp   1:2

element number of state 2
element startp 1:1
element endp   1:2
element incoming_symbol an integer
element v toComplete
element item: an expression -> an integer.

element number of state 1
element startp 1:0
element endp   1:1
element incoming_symbol (
element v toComplete
element item: an expression -> ( .an expression )

Line 1, characters 2-2: Error (parsing)
  Error while analyzing an expression.
Fatal error: exception Invalid_argument("feed: outgoing transition does not exist")
```

Does anyone know why this error was raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before feeding `)`, we should first reduce, the following code works:

```
let env_new = force_reduction (find_production 1) env in
let env_new_new = feed (T T_RPAREN) startp () endp env_new in
(lex, input_needed env_new_new)
```

For `(1+2` for instance, we should reduce twice before feeding `)`, the following code works:

```
let env_new = force_reduction (find_production 1) env in
let env_new_new = force_reduction (find_production 3) env_new in
let env_new_new_new = feed (T T_RPAREN) startp () endp env_new_new in
(lex, input_needed env_new_new_new)
```